# how to add try catch exception for spring integration flow to achieve nested transactions

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to handle nested transactions in spring integration flow. Basically i have a process that fetches all the orders from database and process it order by order, in case of exception thrown on single order, all the orders processed are getting rolled back.

```
    IntegrationFlows.from("perOrder")
         .filter(Order.class, order -> order.getItems().size() > 0)
         .handle(orderHandler, "handle") /*someway i way want to add try/catch for this method here so that 
if handle method throws exception, want to suppress for that order and mark as failure only for that order */
         .get();

public class OrderHandler {
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
   public handle() {
      processing code 
      throw exception in case of any validation failure
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose we provide an *adviceChain* to be injected into the endpoint of that `handle()`:

```
.handle((GenericHandler<?>) (p, h) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
                }, e -> e.advice(retryAdvice()))
```

You can inject there any available `Advice` implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain, including `TransactionInterceptor`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#tx-handle-message-advice

The best way to have a *try...catch* semantics is with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. See its description in the Docs and also its JavaDocs.

Comment: Thanks i will try the option mentioned